# segmentation fault after cv2.imshow([winname], [mat])

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, opencv, computer-vision

how can I debug the segfault in python? I don't know how to read the backtrace. but I provided it here

cv2.imshow('hsv',hsv) is the last thing the script executes

gdb python3 backtrace

```
Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffd00f7013 in ?? () from /home/speed/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.libs/libQtGui-903938cd.so.4.8.7
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0x00007fffd00f7013 in  () at /home/speed/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.libs/libQtGui-903938cd.so.4.8.7
#1  0x00007ffff4e25fe1 in g_main_context_check () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff4e26570 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff4e26962 in g_main_loop_run () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff4bd7dae in ffi_call_unix64 () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff4bd771f in ffi_call () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff55ebe6a in  () at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#7  0x00007ffff55eda48 in  () at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#8  0x00007ffff55e1cb9 in  () at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/_gi.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#9  0x00000000005aa6ec in _PyObject_FastCallKeywords ()
#10 0x000000000050abb3 in  ()
#11 0x000000000050c5b9 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#12 0x0000000000508245 in  ()
#13 0x000000000050a080 in  ()
#14 0x000000000050aa7d in  ()
#15 0x000000000050c5b9 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#16 0x0000000000509d48 in  ()
#17 0x000000000050aa7d in  ()
#18 0x000000000050c5b9 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#19 0x0000000000508245 in  ()
#20 0x000000000050a080 in  ()
#21 0x000000000050aa7d in  ()
#22 0x000000000050c5b9 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#23 0x0000000000509d48 in  ()
#24 0x000000000050aa7d in  ()
#25 0x000000000050c5b9 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#26 0x0000000000508245 in  ()
#27 0x000000000050b403 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#28 0x0000000000635222 in  ()
#29 0x00000000006352d7 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#30 0x0000000000638a8f in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#31 0x0000000000639631 in Py_Main ()
#32 0x00000000004b0f40 in main ()
```

Comment: Can you share more of your program (see [mcve])?

Comment: show the code that's constructing `hsv`

Comment: I am having a very hard time isolating the issue, it is hard to tell what exactly causes it now every time I try to recreate the issue within a small loop, but nothing segfaults. https://github.com/SpeedrunnerG55/EDAutopilot is a fork I made of the original repo, with the changes I made to make it work on my system. steps to recreate the issue with this code is to run ``sudo python3 autopilot.py`` then press the home key to start and in a few seconds, it segfaults.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the HSV image just the fact that the function is being called and, it triggering the segfault. since I get the same behavior if I call it anywhere else in the script, with other image objects

Comment: might be a bug in imshow that was never fixed see https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/501